# iOS location from lat and long

Tags: objective-c, ios, location, latitude-longitude

I am new to iOS development. I have a value of latitude and longitude. I want to get the name of the location using the latitude and longitude? Is it possible in iOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes its possible its called [reverse geocoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_geocoding). You need to first import `CoreLocation` framework then use [`CLGeocoder`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLGeocoder_class/Reference/Reference.html) in iOS5 (and above). For iOS4 and below its `mkreversegeocoder`. Here's how to get address using `CLGeocoder, just feed it the location object and it will do the rest.

```
[self.geoCoder reverseGeocodeLocation: locationManager.location completionHandler: 
     ^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {

         //Get nearby address
         CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];

         //String to hold address
         NSString *locatedAt = [[placemark.addressDictionary valueForKey:@"FormattedAddressLines"] componentsJoinedByString:@", "];

         //Print the location to console
         NSLog(@"I am currently at %@",locatedAt);

     }];
```

The `placemarks` array that you get are instances of [`CLPlacemark`](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLPlacemark_class/Reference/Reference.html) objects. IT gives you access to -

```
Accessing the Placemark Attributes
  name  property
  addressDictionary  property
  ISOcountryCode  property
  country  property
  postalCode  property
  administrativeArea  property
  subAdministrativeArea  property
  locality  property
  subLocality  property
  thoroughfare  property
  subThoroughfare  property
  region  property
```

Answer (score 1):

Another simple method is to use Google map rest api, Make web service call to following url and it will return a json containing location details

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=10.03,10.03&sensor=false

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can use [`CLGeocoder`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLGeocoder_class/Reference/Reference.html) for iOS5 and later.

You can use [`MKReverseGeocoder`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKReverseGeocoder_Class/Reference/Reference.html) if you have to support previous OS version.

Comment: mkreversegeocoder is old deprecated api. you should use `CLGeocoder`, please correct your answer before someone downvotes

Answer (score 0):

Other than MKReverseGeocoder,I recommend you to use google api. I am using it in my app, no crashes and quick response.